# Django summernote. Избавиться от <p><br></p>

Tags: python, django

Summernote по-умолчанию в поля textarea добавляет `<p><br></p>`.

Как удалить эти теги?

Answer (score 0):

В HTML файле, где вы выводите этот `summernote`, вы должны поставить фильтр `| safe`.

Например:

```
{{ content | safe }}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую